# IBM DB2 console doesn't work after SSL certificate update

Tags: ssl, db2, ssl-certificate

I have an issue with IBM DB2 console. After updating expired certs (using [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ias?topic=certificates-console-certificate) instruction) it just stopped work. It happened just right after I uploaded the new cert using web console web interface.

```bash
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect X.X.X.X:8443
Connecting to X.X.X.X
CONNECTED(00000003)
40077A228B7A0000:error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:645:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 306 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

The database cluster itself works well.

How can I check DB2 Console certs? Does DB2 store them in a location returned by "db2 get dbm cfg" command? Can I temporarily disable SSL certs for the console to make it work?